# What does the phrase "have no idea" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

Have no idea is a phrase appears many times in the book [We have no idea: A guide to the unknown universe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735211515), for example in the title, or in this sentence:

> It's the biggest chunk of reality, and we almost have no idea what it is

My question is: What does the phrase "have no idea" mean? Can we understand it literally that people haven't got any idea about something or it means that people don't know about something?

I know that it's quite confusing and may be trivial question, but I'm translate from English to my native language, so I have to find the most exact words to describe that phrase, so please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the expression is peculiar to English. In Hungarian the phrase "fogalmam since" (literally "I have no idea") is used in much the same way.

Comment: It's an emphatic way of saying, 'I do not know anything about this'. Whose dog is it tore up your front garden ? _I have no idea_. It can be used as a way of dissociating oneself from any involvement or any responsibility.

Comment: What's confusing? The universe, your interpretation of its meaning, or your question? (I'm just kidding) I have *almost* no idea what you're trying to ask... would be true if I didn't have an idea what the idiom meant but I do have *some* idea. It's just another way of saying  "I haven't a clue" :)))

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly literal, the subject may in fact have some ideas. To "have no idea" means that whatever ideas the subject does have, if any, are either highly uncertain (usually, when the speaker is the subject) or presumed to be incorrect (usually, when the subject is someone else).

If I say "I/we have no idea", I mean that I am / we are highly unsure, though I probably have at least some vague thoughts on the matter. If I say "he has no idea", I mean that I think he is either ignorant or wrong.

Comment: I disagree with your added note that I/we "probably have at least some vague thoughts on the matter." The phrase "I have no idea" means "I don't know" and does not implicate even the vaguest notion. To the contrary, it's synonymous with (the somewhat old-fashioned), "I haven't the vaguest notion" or "I haven't the slightest clue"/"I don't have a clue."

Comment: @lolite_Jay I agree completely that "no idea" does not imply any idea in the slightest. I thought it was worth pointing out, though, that it certainly doesn't rule it out, and many people use it to convey a looser sense of ignorance, e.g. someone who "has no idea" what their spouse has planned for a special weekend away would not be telling a lie if they did, in fact, have some pretty strong hunches.

Comment: I find that to be an inappropriate use for "no idea," actually. Having no idea/clue means having had no inkling of it at all, so one could only use the phrase ironically (and in fact we often do, in precisely those situations: "REA-uh-lly? I had NOooo idea!" *with dramatic eyeroll*).  If you had a hunch, you'd say you had a hunch, or suspected. The only exception: "I noticed X and Y, but I had no idea they were actually serious about it!" (here the predicted outcome was too far-out to take seriously, so it's the spouse's "real plans/intentions" that eluded understanding).

Comment: To be somewhat pedantic, it should be clarified that *I have no idea* is an idiom (meaning roughly *I don't know at all*), that is compatible with one's having quite a few ideas about the relevant subject matter (just not the idea about its aspect that is in focus). For example, I can say that I have no idea whether the stock of XY corporation will increase or decrease in value next year, but in saying that have very good ideas of what that corporation is, how the value of stock fluctuates, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

No [idea](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/idea) means you are 0% aware of it or completely unconscious of it.

> #1: "Any conception existing in the mind as a result of mental understanding, awareness, or activity"

Comment: This is true, but lacks reputable sources. Even if you're basing this off of your native-speaker-knowledge, you should at least add details, examples, and expand on your answer so that it adds to the information in the other responses.

Comment: Please expand your answer per @Heartspring. While other answers pick up on the common use of the phrasing, yours is more precise by denotation. The words mean *do not know at all*, although they often connote or imply a wealth of other bits. Cain could well have said "Abel? Where? I have no idea!"

Comment: This is a reasonable explication of the literal meaning of *have no idea*, but the phrase is an idiom whose meaning is not a result of straightforwardly combining the meanings of its parts.

Answer (score -1):

To "have no idea" expresses that you don't have enough information to make a definite statement about something. So one could in fact have some feeling or suspect but still not feel confident enough in the facts to state your opinion.

Comment: Surely that's 'have only vague ideas about ...'?